# how to match parentheses with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression to match outer brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546433/regular-expression-to-match-outer-brackets)

I'm trying to match a string that contains parentheses but escaping the parentheses with a backslash gives me an error "unrecognized escape sequence". How do i match the parenthesis and retrieve whats inside?

Comment: You cannot match *balanced* parenthesis with a regexp (which is a finite state automaton, but balancing parenthesis requires more, e.g. a stack or counting automaton which have an infinite set of states).

Comment: You should be able to escape parentheses with a backslash, perhaps you could provide us with some code that you have tried?

Comment: all i need is a simple "text text text (stuff i need to get) text text" it doesnt need to have nested parenthesis or anything i just cant figure out how to get it to match one single parentheses character without giving me the unrecognized escape sequence error

Comment: the code ive tried looks pretty much like this: "\((\"([^\"]+)\")\)". The backslash escapes the double quote fine but it doesnt work when i try to put a backslash in front of the parenthesis

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Actually, .NET regexes can match balanced parentheses correctly, using `(?<DEPTH>)` and `(?<-DEPTH>)` counters.

Answer (score 0):

use Regex.Escape(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx

Comment: How would i go about distinguishing between the parenthesis i expect in the string and the parenthesis that are telling the regex what I want to return from the string?

Comment: something like string pattern = Regex.Escape("[") + "(.*?)]"; you can get more from the link i provided.